# Binding with parent DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding, devexpress

I'm trying to bind combobox editor in a PropertyGrid to a list.

```
<dxprg:PropertyGridControl SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
     <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="EmployeeCountryID">
          <dxprg:PropertyDefinition.EditSettings>
               <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Countries, ElementName=rootWindow}"
                   ValueMember="CountryId" DisplayMember="CountryName" />                                                                  
          </dxprg:PropertyDefinition.EditSettings>
     </dxprg:PropertyDefinition>
</dxprg:PropertyGridControl>
```

This example is from a third-party control but the problem may be just general. 
The "**rootWindow**" DataContext has been set to a ViewModel which holds a property List(of Country) that I want have as `ItemsSource` in a `Combobox`.

I was trying to access that list by setting the Combobox ItemsSource to the `rootWindow.DataContext.Countries` property but I don't get any data.
Tried also all those RelativeSource FindAncestor bindings but no data appeared either.

Why can't I bind through a DataContext of a given element like this?

Comment: Did you try running the app under debugger and checked output window for any WPF binding errors?

Comment: This became solved. The problem was not with the binding at all but realated to how I defined the third-party control: Instead of EditSettings I should have defined CellTemplate -> DataTemplate.

Comment: Cool. Please write your comment as answer and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became solved. The problem was not with the binding at all but realated to how I defined the third-party control: Instead of EditSettings I should have defined CellTemplate -> DataTemplate.